# importing Buefy - Console error: Vue.protoype missing

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, buefy

I want to use `Buefy` in a new Vue 3 Project. It should support Vue 3 as I read.

In the `Buefy` Docs is mentioned to integrate it with the following lines ([source](https://buefy.org/documentation/start))

```js
import Buefy from 'buefy';
import 'buefy/dist/buefy.css';

Vue.use(Buefy);
```

To the createApp() method I applied the given code in the main.js-file:

```js
createApp(App).use(Buefy).mount('#app')
```

By executing the Vue Script there's the error in browsers console "Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "$buefy", Vue.prototype is undefined" and I receive a blank page. No error while compiling. Looked the error already up, got no solution.

How can I fix this error to use `Buefy`? Or have I made a mistake in advance?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Vue.prototype` is the object onto which plugins try to install in Vue 2.  In Vue 3, plugins are not registered this way, and does not support the old syntax, which is why you got this error.

This indicates that the package/installation is not available for Vue 3.  This is confirmed in the discussion thread for GitHub Issue [#2505](https://github.com/buefy/buefy/issues/2505) in the [Buefy](https://github.com/buefy/buefy) package, in which it has recently been stated that the Vue 3 branch is still a work-in-progress.

So for now you'll have to wait until it supports Vue 3, or switch to Vue 2 to use Buefy.

Comment: I found this GH issue several times, but oviously I missunderstood. Clear statement now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is today at 23.11.2021 an v3 version available?